# Error in DB2 ( CARDINALITY)

Tags: sql, db2, syntax-error

Does someone knows how can i solve that problem bellow ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRDLIB.COUNTER( sROWS INT)
RETURNS TABLE (
ROW_ID INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
CARDINALITY 50
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE t3 INT default 0;
    WHILE t3>sROWS DO
        SET t3=t3+1;
        PIPE (t3);
    END WHILE;
    RETURN;
END@
```

Error message

```
Multiple or conflicting keywords involving the "CARDINALITY" clause are present.. SQLCODE=-628, SQLSTATE=42613, DRIVER=4.18.60
```

I'm using DB2 V11.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CARDINALITY  clause is not compatible with the PIPE statement. If you remove the cardinality clause then your function will compile.

The PIPE statement returns at most 1 row at a time, so the cardinality clause is not relevant.

You might use the CARDINALITY clause with an external table function .

Comment: Thanks mao !  I didnt know that !   In next queries i will follow your instructions.